# How to set log level when running Gauge tests via Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, logging, gauge, getgauge

When running my Gauge tests via `mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs` the console output is polluted with DEBUG output.

```
16:33:46.950 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ...
16:33:46.951 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ...
16:33:46.951 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/maven/net.minidev/json-smart/pom.properties ...
...
16:35:52.676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request PUT ...
16:35:52.676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:35:52.676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> PUT ...
```

How can I set the log level for these tests (when running them via Maven plugin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give to JVM these *Opts*

> mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs
>   -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=**warn**

```
mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn
```

Or 
use quite mode

```
mvn gauge:execute -q -DspecsDir=specs
```

or

```
mvn gauge:execute -Dflags="--verbose=false,--log-level=warn" -DspecsDir=specs
```

Comment: Neither of the thrre commands above work for me. I still see the `DEBUG`output.

Comment: try the last option (updated now) should work, donno how you are invoking the maven goal,

Answer (score 2):

This seems to relate to [MNG-6181](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6181) which has been fixed in version `3.5.0` of Maven. So if you're not on the latest version as of now, you can upgrade the Maven version to make use of the fix.

---

In case you want to manipulate the logging option for all your Maven builds with existing version(3.1 or above), you can try to modify its logger implementation at the file:

```
${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties
```

e.g. On MacOSX, it would be somewhat like-

```
vi /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties
```

and then make sure that the properties include something like these:-

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient=off
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.wire=off
```

---

Alternatively, you can execute your `mvn` command with the [`quiet`](https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html) option to filter out only Error logs. The updated command to be used would be:-

```
mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs -q
```

Comment: by changing the simple logger properties in maveen, it will disable logging global level ( for all maven projects not specific one),

Comment: @RamiReddyPalamakula True and that is specified in the answer as well. ... *all your Maven builds*